# Can't connect remotely to server running redhat (ec2)

Tags: linux, firewall, tcp, webserver, amazon-ec2

I created a RedHat 6.1 VM with EC2. Logged in as root, I installed (unzipped) JDK1.7 in `/root/bin/jdk1.7.0` and installed (unzipped) GlassFish 3.1.1 in `/root/bin/glassfish3`. I set `JAVA_HOME` and `GLASSFISH_HOME` in root's `.bash_profile` and I started GlassFish.

It's definitely running, because if I do a `wget localhost:8080` from the command line, `wget` downloads the `index.html` file. The problem is, when I browse to the machine at `http://ec2-107-20-96-43.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080`, I get nothing.

I added port 8080 to the VM's security group; is there something else I have to do there? Is there something else I have to do on the linux machine to make 8080 visible?

Comment: Are you sure that your server is listening on your forward-facing interface?

Comment: @Chris - thanks for the suggestion; it looks like the problem was with the EC2 security group settings

Comment: Just a suggestion: don't start glassfish as root and don't install software in root's home directory. On the security point of view it's a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some more time with the EC2 security groups.  I allowed all incoming TCP ports and it looks like it's working now.  I guess I didn't have port `8080` open correctly.

Comment: Remember to accept your answer; otherwise it keeps coming back for others to attempt to answer.